# iOS 9.1 has caused an error with my JSON NSURL connection to a PHP page

Tags: php, ios, json, nsurlconnection

Before iOS 9.1 my app had successfully communicated to a .php file on the web to get some database information. All of this communication was completed using `JSON` to store the information between the two. I know have an issue that appears to be related to the packet that is sent to my .php file.

```
if($_POST == null){ // Check for proper posting.

    $handle  = file_get_contents('php://input');
    $body = json_decode($handle, true);
}
else{
    $body == $_POST;        
}
```

The code above appears to be the point of failure. I am receiving a **$_POST** that is not null.

```
-(void)postAuthorize:(NSString*)code :(NSString*)phone{

   //build up the request that is to be sent to the server
   NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.example.com/ex.php"]];

   [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
   [request addValue:@"postValues" forHTTPHeaderField:@"METHOD"];

   //create data that will be sent in the post
   NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
   [dictionary setValue:code forKey:@"authorize"];
   [dictionary setValue:phone forKey:@"device"];

   NSLog(@"Dictionary: %@", dictionary);

   //serialize the dictionary data as json
   NSData *data = [[dictionary copy] JSONValue];

   NSLog(@"Data: %@", data);

   [request setHTTPBody:data]; //set the data as the post body
   [request addValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",(unsigned long)data.length] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
   NSLog(@"data length: %lu", (unsigned long)data.length);
   NSLog(@"Request body %@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:[request HTTPBody] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
   NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
   if(!connection){
       NSLog(@"Connection Failed");
   }

}
```

Above is the code on the iPhone. I have checked the `JSON` in the body of the `URL` Connection to make sure it is not improperly formatted. It doesn't seem to be.

This is the error I get:

> Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840.

But I think this is just because the PHP code is failing. If I bypass the code above and just send back a static value everything goes through fine.

I really need help. Please if anyone can point out what is wrong. I don't know why this has worked for 2 years and now it broke from iOS 9.0 -> 9.1

The problem occurs in my PHP. I am guessing Apple changed something in 9.0/9.1 with the URL Connection that changed the $_POST method.

```
$handle  = file_get_contents('php://input');
$body = json_decode($handle, true);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

change you php code to this-

```
$handle  = file_get_contents('php://input');

if($handle == null || $handle == ""){
    $body = $_POST; 
}else{
    $body = json_decode($handle);
}
```

Comment: How do I view this? I am not that great with PHP.

Comment: Nevermind: I did get some more information ->                                        Request body <br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: body in <b>example.php</b> on line <b>119</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: results in <b>example.php</b> on line <b>69</b><br />
{"error":"501"}

Comment: you can view that in your objective-c code as url connection response.

Comment: and the error you are receiving is because you are using body variable which is not defined or initialised before you using it.

Comment: Ok that error was related to the == instead of a single =. But I have new info. This is what is in the $_POST method                                                       -> Array
(
    [{"authorize":"","device":"iPhone"}] => 
)

Comment: now use this code and tell me what output you are getting -

$handle  = file_get_contents('php://input');
echo $handle; die;

Comment: The output I get is as above: Array([{"authorize":"","device":"iPhone"}] => )

Comment: use this now - 
$handle = file_get_contents('php://input'); echo $handle; die;

Comment: response to that -> Response body {"authorize":"","device":"iPhone"}

Comment: Thank you for walking me through this. I understand the process a lot better now. Basically my php else statement from the original question was executing and the code within it was wrong. I actually don't think I even need an if else. the code is the same regardless of $_POST == null.